# jmeter execution comparison with previous build in Jenkins

Tags: jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am interested to publish jmeter report in Jenkins and set the pipeline as "failed" if there are degradation in terms of performances between the previous executions.

Below the configuration set in my Jenkinsfile for my jmeter results:

```
                perfReport filterRegex: '',
                        relativeFailedThresholdNegative: 0,
                        relativeFailedThresholdPositive: 0,
                        relativeUnstableThresholdNegative: 0,
                        relativeUnstableThresholdPositive: 0,
                        sourceDataFiles: 'resultsJmeter/output/*.xml'
                    }
```

Is there any way to evaluate automatically the previous executions (if any) ?

Answer (score 4):

As per [Performance Trend Reporting](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/Reporting.html) article:

> You can configure the error percentage thresholds and the relative percentage thresholds which would make the project unstable or failed or set them to `-1` to disable the feature

As per [How to Use the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin/)

[image]

> Set the following values:
>
> ```
> Unstable: 10
> Failed: 60
> ```
>
> This configuration will mark the build as unstable when errors are at 10% and as failed when 60% of our requests failed.

The relevant pipeline syntax would be:

```
perfReport errorFailedThreshold: 60, errorUnstableThreshold: 10, filterRegex: '', sourceDataFiles: 'resultsJmeter/output/*.xml'
```

for the relative to the previous build:

```
perfReport relativeFailedThresholdNegative: 10, relativeFailedThresholdPositive: 60, relativeUnstableThresholdNegative: 5, relativeUnstableThresholdPositive: 30, sourceDataFiles: 'resultsJmeter/output/*.xml', filterRegex: ''
```

Comment: is it checking also degradation in terms of time? I mean, if a rest api in my previous changes took 10ms and after some changes it takes 10s, is it forced to fail?